# Destroy tkinter button and menu immediately

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new at using tkinter and I am trying to develop an interface which takes initial user input, uses it to grab data from a database, then changes the widgets in the window to gather different user input.

Right now my app will take a string from an entry widget and a string from a selection menu. I then have a start button which is connected to a function that I wrote to start the data gathering process.

When this button is clicked, I would like for the drop down menu, entry box, and button to be deleted so that I can add other widgets in their place, like the button I am trying to add in the `cycle_bins` function in the below abridged code.

I know that I need to use the destroy() function to delete these widgets, but the issue that I am having is that the original widgets do not get removed until the whole function is completed, whereas, I would like the widgets to be removed before I preform the rest of the function, so that I can continue to gather other user input, with different widgets.

I am using the following abridged code:

```
# code to get data from database and start the count
def start_count(cycle_count, tmstamp):
    # delete original widgets (not working, does not remove immediately)
    button.destroy()
    ent_date.destroy()
    menu.destroy()
    
    # get data from db
    bin_list = fn.get_info(cycle_count, tmstamp) # returns dataframe of bins and locations
    
    # call next function to start cycle of data
    cycle_bins(bin_list)

# code to cycle through bins returned from db and ask for user input
def cycle_bins(bins): 
    # add new button to go to next bin and record user input
    new_button = tk.Button(
        text="new",
        width=25,
        height=5,
        bg="grey"
    )
    new_button.pack()
    
    # code loop to cycle through list of bins and gather user input from newly added widgets

# create window code
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x250")
window.title("Cycle Count")
greeting = tk.Label(text="Cycle Count", height=5)
greeting.pack()

# entry widget
ent_date = tk.Entry(master=window)
ent_date.pack()

# drop down menu
count_type = tk.StringVar(window)
menu = tk.OptionMenu(window, count_type, "AL", "AU", "BL", "BU", "Audit")
menu.pack()

# start button
button = tk.Button(
    text="Start Cycle Count",
    width=25,
    height=5,
    bg="grey",
    command = lambda: start_count(count_type.get(), ent_date.get())
)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I thought that the problem may have been that the window would not update with the new widgets until the whole function ended, so I tried coding a simple function that had only the code to destroy the original widgets, which I called in `start_count`, but that gave me the same problem that I am still running into, the window would not destroy old widgets and add new ones until the `start_count` function was completed. I also have not been able to find any other people who have had a similar problem online to find the answer.

The reason why I need the window to update immediately is because when the original button calls `start _count`, that function calls the `cycle_bins` function, which in the official code, has a large loop that loops through the data frame passed in to it by the `start_count` function and asks for user input, through the new widgets, based on the current row of the data frame. But, as the program stands now, the loop and code in the `cycle_bins` function would have to be completed before any updates to the window would be made as it is called by the `start_count`. So the window would have a depressed button and two input widgets sitting above while the rest of the program runs.

I should also explain that I have functions like `fn.get_info()` in a separate file to keep things more organized and clear. The only reason I have the two functions shown in this post in the same file of the tkinter window is because they edit the window, which as far as I know must be done in the same file, as per the tutorials that I have been following on creating a tkinter GUI.

Please let me know if you have run across this issue before and have found a solution, or if I am going about this the wrong way and there is a simpler way of doing it. Your expertise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried using `root.update()` method?

Comment: I just added that function and it solved the issue. I cannot believe that it was that simple, thank you for your help @jakubSzlaur!

Comment: I added an answer to your question - consider giving it the green arrow! :)

Comment: I would suggest using [`update_idletasks()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) instead—that's its purpose and it's safer to use than `update()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `root.update()` method.

No problem.